# How to change Symfony2 Response Content-Type?

Tags: symfony, response, mime-types

This is my code

```
public function widgetAction(Request $request) {
    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response(
            $this->renderView('WidgetoBundle:Widget:widget.html.twig'
    ));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
    return $response;
}
```

I'm using it as src of script i.e., `<script ... src="{{ url_for_my_action }}" ></script>`.

The problem is that on my localhost I'm getting a response with content type as it is in code (**application/javascript**). But, when I call it from server (1and1 shared hosting) the response is **text/html** type.

**UPDATE**

I've just moved my method to DefaultController from WidgetController and now content is correct application/javascript in both cases. No other changes. Same template used..
Any idea why it is working now??

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "in strong text type" ? What is the response header you're getting on your shared hosting webspace. `Content-Type: ...` ? Does the route/URL include a file-extension ?

Comment: Sorry, typo what I mean is text/html. Route is the same,.. Im not changing it

Comment: Could be a caching issue?

Comment: I clear cache on local and webhost

Comment: Please see update -I've just moved my method to DefaultController from WidgetController and now content is correct application/javascript in both cases. No other changes. Same template used.. Any idea why it is working now??

Comment: It sounds like something at the host is caching it - something between the webserver and the public internet - a varnish proxy or something.

Comment: Could be your browser cache, use Ctrl+F5 to refresh the page. You can try to switch back to your other controller and see what happens